# how c manage data with different size from CPU word size?

Tags: c, memory-management, cpu, low-level

while i was taking a course in hardware/software interface, our teacher said the cpu get the data using the word machine, for example, the CPU can get the value at address **0x00** but cannot get the value at address **0x01** but the value at address **0x00** + (word-size:normally it 4 byte), so i want to understand how we can use short int in **c** that contain only 2 byte?

Comment: The cpu loads a wide cache line and masks out unnecessary bytes.

Comment: By reading 4 bytes, but only using 2 of them.

Comment: so what the point of using short if there is no performance/storage saving?

Comment: when the language was written there were 8 bit systems and definite performance advantages.  If you use an array of them you will save memory if you use smaller sizes bytes vs shorts vs ints.  Not all processors use the same size words/registers.  A number of processors have instructions that allow for the smaller data types without requiring extra instructions

Comment: @karim The "point of using short" is space.  Two 2-byte `short` fit in the same space as one 4-byte `int`, thus a storage savings.  The cost is sometimes a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32 bit processor uses 4 bytes for integer, So first let me explain about memory banking

**memory banking**= If the processor had used the single byte addressing scheme,it would take 4 memory cycles to perform a read/write operation. So from processors point of view memory is banked as shown. 
[image]

**So if a integer is stored as in the address range 0x0000-0x0003 ie;4 byes ,it just requires a single memory read/write cycle so the processor is relieved from the extra memory cycles and hence improved performance.**

**Also it is also possible that a variable allocation can start from a number which is not a multiple of four hence it might require 2 or more memory cycles(float,double etc..) in accordance with how they are stored**. The CPU fetches the data in minimum number of read cycles.

In short data type only two bytes of the memory are allocated and if it starts from 0x0001 then it ends in 0x0002 still 1 read cycle is required for it. But the advantage is that **in integer it allocates 4 bytes where as the short allocates two byes so the two bytes is saved from the integer data type. So storage is improved**

Reference:

[Geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/)

[IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/)

Comment: Talking of banks is somewhat overkill.  The important point is that the "native" memory access (in this example) is 32-bits wide.

Answer (score 4):

Different CPU's have different memory access restrictions. One common form is to allow access at any byte offset, but suffer performance penalties if this occurs because two word-aligned transfers might be needed in order to retrieve all bytes necessary for the operation. The second form simply disallows non-aligned memory access.

In the first case, the compile has nothing to worry about, memory can be "packed" or word-aligned and both will work, but one will be faster and one will use less memory.

In the second case, the compiler must generate code to get an un-aligned data into the correct  register location(s) to allow arithmetic and logical operations to occur. These operations shift and/or mask bits in byte-sized units. For example a 4-byte load may be needed to load a 2-byte variable. In this instance 2 bytes of the data will likely need to be "zeroed" and the 2 "good" bytes may need to be shifted into the low-order bits of the register. All of this is the responsibility of the compiler, but it adds overhead to access the data. On the other hand, it means the data occupies less memory when not stored in a register. This can be important if you have a large amount of data, such as an array of a few million integers; storing it in half the space may actually make the program run faster (even given the above overhead), since twice as many array values fit in the cache.